# Como usar queryselector em um input?

Tags: javascript

Olá, preciso selecionar o valor que está dentro de um input, o valor é variavel de 1 a 12, mas não sei como fazer isso, aqui está o HTML do input:

```
<input type="text" id="mudarUnidadePacote" class="input-quantity ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" value="0" ng-model="ctrl.boxQuantity" ng-blur="ctrl.updateBoxQuantity()" packsize="12">
```

Esse é meu código (aparece que eu consegui selecionar o elemento mas não aparece o numero, entre 0 e 12).

```
let quantidade = document.getElementById("mudarUnidadePacote").textContent;
alert(quantidade)
```

Comment: Vinícius, [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) pega um nodo de texto que é filho do `input`. Porém inputs não tem filhos pois não são contêiners. O que você quer é a propriedade `value` do [`InputHTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#value)

Comment: E seria legal você [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar as tags dos frameworks que você está usando, pois `ng-model` não faz parte do HTML padrão e pode mudar completamente a resposta mais aconselhada para o seu caso.

Comment: @fernandosavio peço perdão, primeira questão minha aqui no stack, no caso o framework é Angular.

Answer (score 2):

O [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) é usado para obter o nó de texto que pode estar dentro de um elemento HTML.

Para obter o valor de um `input`, `select` ou `textarea`, você deve utilizar a propriedade **`value`**.

Assim:

```js
const field = document.querySelector('#my-field');

field.addEventListener('input', () => {
  // Obtemos o valor:
  console.log(field.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="my-field" />
```